# Потоки и gil для qt

Tags: python, qt, winapi

У меня чисто теоретический вопрос. Всем известно, что gil блокирует потоки, запущенные из модуля threading. Но когда мы используем pyqt, то можно использовать qthread либо можно вообще вызывать из вин апи createthread. Будет ли распространяться блокировка qil на эти потоки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не будет. Поэтому придётся заниматься синхронизацией самостоятельно и самостоятельно отвечать за последствия ошибок.