# Насколько адекватно будет работать тяжёлая Python программа в .exe?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Начал разрабатывать большое приложение на питоне, прочитал про способы компиляции в .exe файлы. Появился вопрос насколько адекватно будет всё работать если написать тяжёлую программу которую распространять  с помощью .exe? Приложение это текстовый редактор для писателей, с полным функционалом форматирования текста, связью с облаком и дополнительными окнами с заметками.
Для интерфейса использую PyQt

Comment: наверное большая и тяжёлая программа упрётся в GIL  при больших текстах (были такие темы но с редакторами+подсветка синтаксиса на tkinter а не pyqt5)

Comment: @Интик На сколько я понимаю из этой статьи, если постараться, то это не будет проблемой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929327/Потоки-и-gil-для-qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо пробовать под конкретную программу. Соберите и тестируйте желательно на виртуалке с не сильно мощным железом(будут заметнее косяки).
Пару лет назад делал софт с pyqt, для себя понял что не стоит писать весь софт в один exe. Скорее всего из за распаковки первоначальный запуск может быть долгим.

В целом больше нравится вариант тянуть окружение(embedded) + собственная exe обвязка.
Из недостатков программы прилично так разрастается в объёме. Можно конечно же вручную почистить окружение но лишние телодвижения в общем на любителя.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

На примере auto-py-to-exe могу сказать, что даже пустое приложение, собранное в exe вести около 5 МБайт, однако сам код и подключаемые библиотеки не сильно увеличивают размер итогового исполняемого файла, осторожнее нужно быть с графическими ресурсами. Не вижу причин переживать из-за размера, но есть смысл уточнить возможность сборки в exe всего набора используемых модулей, могут быть несовместимости и подводные камни.

Comment: Спасибо большое